# What is the correct way for handling which button is pressed with NSAlert

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have added two buttons to the `NSAlert` object, at the moment the return code for button one is `1001`, and for button to by default its `1000`. I need to determine effectively which button in a given alert is pressed without working with magic numbers. It gets messy otherwise.

```
-(void)showErrorMessage:(NSString*)errorMessage{
    NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
    [alert setMessageText:@"Error"];
    [alert setInformativeText:errorMessage];
    [alert setAlertStyle:NSCriticalAlertStyle];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Retake test"];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel test"];
    [alert beginSheetModalForWindow:window modalDelegate:self didEndSelector:@selector(retakeFingerPrintAlert:returnCode:contextInfo:) contextInfo:nil];
}

- (void)retakeTestAlert:(NSAlert *)alert
                    returnCode:(int)returnCode
                   contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo{
    NSLog(@"clicked %d button\n", returnCode);


    //I want to determine very clearly which button is being pressed in the NSAlert
    //I dont want to work with magic numbers

    //And thus call the below method dependng on the button clicked
    [self onRetakeTest];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to Apple's documentation on "`addButtonWithTitle:`", which you're using:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAlert_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAlert/addButtonWithTitle:)

> The first three buttons are identified positionally as
>   NSAlertFirstButtonReturn, NSAlertSecondButtonReturn,
>   NSAlertThirdButtonReturn in the return-code parameter evaluated by the
>   modal delegate. Subsequent buttons are identified as
>   NSAlertThirdButtonReturn +n, where n is an integer

So the first button should equal [`NSAlertFirstButtonReturn`], which translates to "`1000`". The fourth button should be "`1003`".

Makes sense so far?

Comment: I see. Strangely though, the third button has a value of 1000, and the first button on the left has a value of 1002. Is that the norm for the buttons to be indexed from right to left?

Comment: I am guessing it might be different depending on the language / script you're using.  Are you using English for your UI?  :-)

Comment: It's usual, under OSX, for "OK" to be bottom-right, and "Cancel" to be to the left, so that might account for the order.

Comment: Lol, yes @michael, I am.